# Proper name for columns in a join table

Tags: database

Say I have two tables, table_A and table_B, with a many-to-many relationship using a join table A_join_B. In A_join_B there are of course two columns, foreign keys to table_A and to table_B respectively.

From the perspective of table_A, the first column in A_join_B is the key to itself, while the second column is the key to the other table. The meaning is reversed from the perspective of table_B.

My question is: is there a proper name for these 'self' and 'other' keys?

I've been using the names *home key* and *away key* lately, so from the perspective of table_A the first column in A_join_B is the home key and the second column is the away key. I don't think this is conventional though and I can't seem to find anything on Google.

Or, like the name of the join table itself (junction table, association table, xref table etc., etc.), is there no accepted standard terminology for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of disciplines that view databases in different ways.  The relational model of data, entity-relationship model, network data model, object-role modeling and dimensional modeling are just a few of the better known perspectives.  Each of these have their own terminology.  Further confusing matters is the high amount of informal terminology, not to mention misconceptions, that pervade the field.

In the relational model, EF Codd introduced the term foreign key: *"We shall call a domain (or domain combination) of relation R a foreign key if it is not the primary key of R but its elements are values of the primary key of some relation S (the possibility that S and R are identical is not excluded)."*

Thus, in your example, A_join_B consists of two foreign keys which together make up the primary key of that table.  The relational model doesn't take a perspective from one table or another.  It also doesn't distinguish join tables - every table is a relation between sets of values.

The mess of different data modeling approaches in the field makes things confusing.  I recommend you take one model at a time and study it thoroughly, going back to the academic roots of the discipline.  Codd's `A relational model of data for large shared data banks` and Chen's `The entity-relationship model - toward a unified view of data` are two essential papers in the history of data modeling.  They're not difficult to read either - shorter than books, more rigorous than blogs and more educational than product documentation.